# I've mistakenly installed another wordpress in my main domain instead of subdomain

Tags: subdomains, domain

All of sudden, my main domain show me nothing but a newly made website. All of my articles are **lost** now, anyone have idea how to get my old data back? I'm close to get **AdSense** approval.
Please help me **recover** my website.

Comment: How did you do the installation. You will probably need to speak to your host to see if they have a backup.